# How to add QueryParams in detect_intent request with Dialogflow_v2 Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I want to add some custom parameters to a detect_intent() request in Dialogflow_v2 in Python. I have been reading the documentation here and here, and tried different things.

I have created a QueryParameters object and added a dict to the payload parameters.

```
query_params =  dialogflow.types.session_pb2.QueryParameters
query_params.payload = {"raw_input": "raw message test"}
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
# Initiate client
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
text_input = dialogflow.types.session_pb2.TextInput(text="This is the normal input message.", language_code='nl')

# Define query input
query_input = dialogflow.types.session_pb2.QueryInput(text=text_input)
session_path = "SESSION_PATH"

# Add query params
query_params = dialogflow.types.QueryParameters
query_params.payload = {"New parameter": "I want to send this parameter in the request"}

# Detect intent
session_client.detect_intent(session=session_path, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params)
```

**Throwing the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-48049dcfc9c7> in <module>
     12 
     13 # Detect intent
---> 14 session_client.detect_intent(session=session_path, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params)

/home/casper/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dialogflow_v2/gapic/sessions_client.py in detect_intent(self, session, query_input, query_params, input_audio, retry, timeout, metadata)
    266             query_input=query_input,
    267             query_params=query_params,
--> 268             input_audio=input_audio,
    269         )
    270         return self._inner_api_calls['detect_intent'](

TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.QueryParameters got GeneratedProtocolMessageType.
```

Can anybody help me adding a payload in QueryParams to the detect text intent in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider and try below approach.

Per this [Dialogflow QueryParameters](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow/latest/dialogflow_v2/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflow_v2.types.QueryParameters) documentation, `QueryParameters` accepts `Struct`. With this, you may **create a Protbuf struct from your Dictionary** by using the code below.

```py
#Creation of Struct
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct

    my_payload = Struct()
    my_payload.update({"New parameter": "I want to send this parameter in the request"})
```

Now you may pass `my_payload` to your query parameter and it should accept it.